# Why doesn't stackoverflow take into consideration different timezones?

Tags: support, timezone, comments

Let's say that you ask a question at 20:00 BST, you wait for comments, then let's say you wait until 04:00 BST in the morning, you then go to sleep and in the morning you discover that you can not longer add comments. I did not find anything in the FAQ. Can someone please explain to me how does it work?

Comment: Being able to comment has nothing to do with time. You can still add comments on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4

Comment: Rats, the inline-retagging loophole is gone so I can't remove the belongs-on-meta tag from the migrated question. Sometimes I don't like it when Jeff & Company get things done.

Comment: What is BST? I mean, "B" is for Bacon, I get that much. But the rest?

Comment: @Pekka: Bacon & Sausage Time, obviously.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have two different user accounts: [an older unregistered user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/333741/mark) which asked the question, and a [new user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/334590/mark). You must have tried to comment with the new user on the old user's question. You can't do this as you don't have enough reputation to comment on others' questions (50 reputation is required).

Comment: I went ahead and flagged the question for moderator attention in case none of them sees this.

Answer (score 1):

The time zone is irrelevant here - as is time taken to comment. In other words, the answer to "why" is "because it doesn't matter" :)

What are you being told when you try to add a comment?

Comment: This should really be a comment. :)

Comment: Ha, I know why, you need to be registered to be able to add comments

Comment: ...But there is no add comment link on yesterday question

Comment: @Mark maybe because it's closed? can you post a link?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775774/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-this-array-comparison-problem

Comment: @Mark: I still have an 'add comment' button  there  .. but first I need to open the '15 more comments' thingy. For me seeing the button is not time related, but seems comment-count related.

Comment: I do not have it, even if I'm logged in, I opened all the ..more comments but I do not have add comment link

Comment: @Mark: How much rep do you have?

Comment: I have just 1 reputation

Comment: Hmm... as it's your own question, you should be able to comment on answers. You're absolutely sure you're logged in as the user that asked it? If you click on your name at the top, does it show that question?

Answer (score 0):

I have merged your accounts. As has been remarked you had <s>two</s> *several* different unregistered accounts, one registered. You should now have all your super powers restored.